# Group Theory vs Graph Theory

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, category-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I would like to know that,

> 1. **For a given graph can we associate a finite group functorially?**
> 2. **If there are more than one such groups, what are the differences and similarities between them?**

Here by a graph I mean a finite, simple, connected one. It may de directed or undirected.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph

Comment: What group are you associating to a given graph? Its automorphism group?

Comment: More conditions required. Associated in *what* sense?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: I add few details in to my question. Are they enough?

Comment: Delete one edge of $K_{n,m}$. The image set isn't a group. Also: there are *two elements* of $\mathbb{Z}_n\times\mathbb{Z}_m$ associated with each edge.

Comment: Your edited post still doesn't make sense. Are you just looking for a bijection between the edge set of a given graph and some group, without any additional structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to associate a group to a graph, some interesting, some artificial. I'm not sure what the motivation is behind the question.

Given a graph $G$, the automorphisms of $G$ form a group called $\mbox{Aut}(G)$.

Given a connected graph $G$, think of it as a topological space, pick a base point, and consider the fundamental group $\pi_1(G,x_0)$. This is a free group generated by the cycles in $G$ which start and end at $x_0$.

Given a graph $G$, the set of maps from the vertices of $G$ to any group $H$ is a group. Same for maps from the edges.

And so on.

Answer (score 4):

Other ways to associate a group (but typically infinite ones) are the following:

**Graph of Groups**: See e.g. *Serre, "Trees"* or the corresponding wiki-article. These are groups arising from actions on graphs (trees). See also its generalization, called *Complexes of groups* (see e.g. *Bridson, Haefliger, "Metric spaces of non-positive curvature"*

**RAAGs**: Right angled Artin Groups. Groups given by presentations depending on the structure of the given graph.

or more generally

**Graph groups**: Generalizing RAAGs and Coxeter groups.

Answer (score 3):

I did my thesis on something similar:
Basically, I mapped an edge-colored graph to a subgroup of a permutation group. Suppose $|G|=n$ and label its vertices from $1$ to $n$. Then, each color used for the coloration of the edges of the graph is mapped to a transposition in $S_n$:

For a color $\alpha$ used on the edges $v_{k_1}v_{k_2}, v_{k_3}v_{k_4}, \cdots, v_{k_{l-1}}v_{k_l} $, the corresponding transposition in $S_n$ is $(k_1k_2)(k_3k_4)\cdots(k_{l-1}k_l)$. Then, the corresponding subgroup of $S_n$ is the group generated by all the transpositions given by the different colors.

More intuitively, it can be seen as putting a number next to each vertex of the graph. Then, calling a color (let's say blue) will switch the labels on all pairs of vertices that are adjacent by a blue edge. Since the edge-coloration requires that no two adjacent vertices have the same color, this manipulation is well-defined. Then, it's possible to call other colors and so on. The resulting group is the set of all the different permutations of numbers that can be found in the graph using this manipulation.

For example, $P_n$ together with its minimal coloration is mapped to $D_{2n}$

Comment: Thank you for you nice answer. I feel this similar to what I am looking for. I'll study this and if you do not mind I would like to share my work with you.

Comment: I found several theorems on this particular topic, I can share them with you if you want !